# SQL having trouble getting desired query

Tags: sql, oracle

Say we have the following relation:
*Author(name,title,language)*

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make query that lists all the authors and how many books in a particular language they made, and if they made none in that language then display zero.

What I've tried so far is this

```
select name, count("language") as SomeLanguage 
from Author 
where "language"='English' 
group by name;
```

Which gives the count of how many books in the specified language they made, but I don't know how to include the other authors that did not write a book in that language.

Example Output:

```
Name | SomeLanguage
----------------
Bill | 4 
Rob  | 1
Bob  | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(case when language = 'English' then 1 else 0 end) as SomeLanguage
from Author 
group by name;
```